# How do you take values from a list and make a list that contains all that items as one string?

Tags: python, list

So let's say we have this list

```
a = ["This", "is", "a", "list"]
```

How do you transform it into this?

```
b = ["This is a list"]
```

Comment: `b = [' '.join(a)]`?

Comment: `b = [' '.join(a)]`?

Comment: To find answers to this question try googling "Python join list of strings".  There is no need to ask this question.

Comment: You could use the method join of strings. For example, '  '.join(a) will join all items of a list with a space between each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["This", "is", "a", "list"]
b = [ ' '.join(a) ]

print(b)
```

Output:

```
['This is a list']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = [" ".join(a)]
```

`" ".join(a)` joins all elements of the array with str separator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use join method of string
b=[" ".join(a)]